# How wait till user go out of the input box then run Method in Angular

Tags: angular

I am calling a method on for an input box to check if the email that user enters is exists or not,  my problem is that with each character that user enters the method will run, I want to wait till user go out of the input so I run the method once.

This is my code that tried - Blur is not working here.

This is HTMl:

```
                <input
                formControlName="emailWork"
                label="Work Email"
                type="text"
                (blur)="onInputblur()"
                [error]="hasError('emailWork', 'required') || hasError('emailWork', 'email')"
                errorMessage="Please enter a valid email address." />
            <span class="error-label"
                *ngIf="addUserForm.get('emailWork').hasError('usernameTaken')">Email already exists
            </span>
```

This is my form in Angular ts file:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.addUserForm = this.fb.group({
        firstName: ['', [Validators.required]],
        lastName: ['', [Validators.required]],
        emailWork: ['', [Validators.email, Validators.required], this.emailValidator()]
    });
}
```

This is on blur:

```
public isBlured: boolean = false; (at the top)

public onInputblur(): void {
    this.isBlured = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.emailValidator();
    }, 250);
}
```

This is method that is checking for email existence:

```
private emailValidator(): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<any> => {
        return this.service.doesUserNameExist(control.value).pipe(
            debounceTime(500),
            map(exists => (!exists ? null : { usernameTaken: true }))
        );
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `updateOn` option for that field

```
 this.addUserForm = this.fb.group({
    firstName: ['', [Validators.required]],
    lastName: ['', [Validators.required]],
    emailWork: ['', {
        validators: [Validators.email, Validators.required],
        asyncValidators: [this.emailValidator()],
        updateOn: 'blur'
    }]
});
```